# In Adobe AEM, how does the parsys component inject styles into the design css file?

Tags: aem

In Adobe AEM ( formerly CQ5 ) the foundation component parsys' design_dialog allows the user to set the "Cell Padding".  Whatever value is entered into the text field will show up in the design css.

For example:

Given that the current page is using /etc/designs/my-design the page output will include reference to the /etc/designs/my-design.css stylesheet virtual path.

If the user configured the parsys cell padding to be 30px then the my-design.css file will include the following:

```
.page_full .par div.section {
  padding: 30px;
}
```

The string "30px" is stored in the jcr:content/page/par/section attribute called div.padding, however, I can't figure out how the parsys.jsp injects it into the my-design.css.

**EDIT:** 
To be clear, the `currentDesign.writeCssIncludes(pageContext);` call in the foundation page headlibs.jsp is the code that sets up the design css includes like so:

```
<link href="/etc/designs/my-design/static.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="/etc/designs/my-design.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

However, it is not clear how to get your own CSS included in the *response body* of the /etc/designs/my-design.css request.

Comment: What do you mean by injecting? What are you trying to accomplish, or is this merely for knowledge?

Comment: The padding gets added dynamically based on the user setting. I want to do a similar thing with my component, but I don't know how this setting gets into the main design.css file.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The parsys doesn't really *inject* the styles, but when you change the design parameters for the parsys component in they are stored the design page and when this is rendered as css by a Design class and the output is contains those updates.

### How the design CSS is rendered

The design information is stored in the `/etc/designs/my-design` as you noticed.  This component for this page supports a css rendition of the information contained.

You can track the source of the rendition using the CQ development tools included in the product...

If you take a look at your design page in crx/de or crx/explorer, you'll notice it has sling:resourceType of `wcm/core/components/designer`.

That will be rendered by the following java class `/libs/wcm/core/components/designer/designer.css.java`.  You can take a look at this file in crx/de also.  I'm not sure the license in that file would allow me to post a snippet here, but you should be able to find it easily yourself.

The class takes the page Resource and adapts the object to a `com.day.cq.wcm.api.designer.Design` instance.

Looking at the dependency finder in the web console, the Design class is provided by the cq-wcm-api bundle.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.day.cq.wcm</groupId>
  <artifactId>cq-wcm-api</artifactId>
  <version>5.5.0</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

This is provided by the jar: `/libs/wcm/core/install/cq-wcm-api-5.5.0.jar`, which is bundled with CQ.

### Customising the design CSS

**Looking at what you are trying to achieve...**
you are able to customise the content of the design page (this is normally by adding a design dialog to the component you are working with) adding any properties/css attributes associated with that component.

For an example of this take a look at logo component within the geometrixx design (`/etc/designs/geometrixx/jcr:content/contentpage/logo`).  This already has a `div img.margin` property which translates to

```
.contentpage div.logo img {
  margin: 1px;
}
```

in the output css (`/etc/designs/geometrixx.css?cacheKiller=xyz`).

Adding a property named `div img.border` with a value of `5px solid red` to this node will output css as:

```
.contentpage div.logo img {
  margin: 1px;
  border: 5px solid red;
}
```

Considering your example, your design content node at `/etc/designs/my-design` should look something like this:

```
+jcr:content
  + page_full
    + par
      + section
        - div .margin = 30px
```

Or in the repository XML format, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:sling="http://sling.apache.org/jcr/sling/1.0" xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0" xmlns:nt="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/nt/1.0"
    jcr:primaryType="cq:Page">
    <jcr:content
        cq:lastModified="{Date}2013-01-13T17:22:51.339+01:00"
        cq:lastModifiedBy="admin"
        cq:template="/libs/wcm/core/templates/designpage"
        jcr:primaryType="cq:PageContent"
        jcr:title="design"
        sling:resourceType="wcm/core/components/designer">
        <page_full jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
            <par jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                <section
                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                    div_x0020_.margin="30px"/>
            </par>
        </page_full>
    </jcr:content>
</jcr:root>
```

Design dialogs (which should be used to customise design content) are described to some extent on the [Developing Components](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/developing/components.html) page.  You can find the design dialog (for an example) of the logo component mentioned above at `/libs/foundation/components/logo/design_dialog.html`

Comment: Finally got the chance to verify this.  It is right on. I was circling around the solution, but not connecting the dots. Thanks.

Comment: I downloaded the cq-content-5.5.0.20120220.zip using CRX Package Manager and decompiled the /jcr_root/libs/wcm/core/install/cq-wcm-core-5.5.6.jar. It is the CSSWriter.class that converts the nodes to CSS styles.  See: http://dev.day.com/content/docs/v5_1/cq-wcm-javadoc/com/day/cq/wcm/core/impl/designer/package-summary.html  Unfortunately, it doesn't (or can't) detect when the class name is overridden by the component's cq:htmlTag.

Answer (score 2):

This change in the CSS is done in the parsys using the Class [IncludeOptions](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/5-5/javadoc/com/day/cq/wcm/api/components/IncludeOptions.html). If you look at the parsys.jsp in foundation components you'll come across usage of this class.
The method getCssClassNames() of the IncludeOptions class returns a modifiable set of css class names to be added to the div tag. 
Thus whenever the section field is authored for a parsys, it is included in the dynamically added to the component's CSS and then the resource is included in the page.

Comment: There may be something here, but, I believe, as you have laid it out, this code only modifies the rendered div tag.  This is similar to the use of the cq:htmlTag node. Therefore, this is not the code that is injecting the user-configured padding value into the "my-design.css" file.  I added more description to the question which may help clarify what I am looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Could anyone help me with the following questions, it seems the question is related [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25755523/cq-custom-tag-dynamic-class-name