# Inserting a class name dynamically on a component's wrapping element

Tags: css, adobe, aem

I am using a `cq:htmlTag` to generate a custom tag for one of the components.

For the "class" property, I know that I could provide a static class name that is part of a CSS file, but my requirement is to have the 'template name' as the class property value.

Does CQ provide a way to use dynamic values?

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box I think not. There are a few workarounds that I could think of:

- Add another tag as a child where you set that class (probably not what you want)
- Use javascript to add it on load (if it is not to late)
- Overlay the parsys and implement your logic there